# Is it possible to set the default size of the window when debugging a UWP project to your local machine?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, xamarin, uwp, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible to set the size of the window when debugging a UWP project to your local machine?

For instance, I want the window to show portrait 800 x 1200 every time I debug.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds to me that you actually want to change the DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences property.

Comment: What is your monitor's resolution? If the height of your monitor's resolution less than 1200, we can not set that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public MainView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

#if DEBUG
    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(800, 1200);
    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
#endif
}
```

Comment: I think it would be good to have conditional `#if DEBUG` since the question is regarding debug session only.